# bind() error 98 - "Address already in use"

Tags: c++, linux, server

If i start local server on Linux, i get "Address already in use" error.

I use `setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR)` but it doesn't help. How can i solve this problem?
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    sockaddr_un s_addr;
    s_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(s_addr.sun_path, "server");

    int s_descriptor = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    const int par = 1;
    if (setsockopt(s_descriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &par, sizeof(int)) < 0){
        cout << "Error setsockopt()";
        return -1;
    }

    if (bind(s_descriptor, (sockaddr *)&s_addr, sizeof(s_addr)) < 0) {
        cout << "Error with bind()\n";
        cout << strerror(errno);
        return -2;
    }

    close(s_descriptor);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kill the existing program that's already using the address+port that you want to use, before starting your program?

Comment: What is the current working directory when you try to run the program? Is there already a file named `server` in that directory? Is there a program already running that uses the same socket file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to create an `AF_UNIX` socket. `AF_UNIX` sockets create a filesystem pipe node to handle connections.

In this case `EADDRINUSE` means that the filesystem node already exists. Nothing might actually be listening on it, but it exists, and `bind()` fails for that reason. It's a quirk of how `AF_UNIX` sockets work. `SO_REUSEADDR` is for `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` sockets, and does not do much for `AF_UNIX` sockets.

```
strcpy(s_addr.sun_path, "server");
```

You will be surprised to find a `server` special pipe file in your current directory. That's the culprit. The solution is very simple:

```
unlink("server");
```

Just before you `bind()`, and now you can bind it.

If you've been paying attention you will now be wondering if anything stops multiple instances of your server starting, creating and `bind()`ing to this `AF_UNIX` socket, and rudely `unlink`ing its predecessor's listening socket, leaving you with multiple instances of the server process, all but one of them now completely useless. This is correct, nothing will stop you from doing that.

Which is why `AF_UNIX` servers will typically employ other means to ensure that only one instance of them is running, like a separate lock file. But that's going to be a separate question...

Comment: Would a separate lock file really be needed? Can't the actual socket file serve as a lock file in this context? A RAII wrapper to remove the socket on exit would be nice in that case of course.

Comment: Yes, removing the socket file on exit would be one approach. Now you have to figure out how to handle SIGKILL... Another approach is to handle a bind() failure by attempting to connect() to the existing socket and see if anyone's home, and if not then `unlink` it and move in. But that's still open to a race condition. So, in the end, you'll begrudgingly conclude that you need a lock file...